# Does MultipartFileStreamProvider efficiently save file uploads?

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have a question regarding the MultipartFileStreamProvider which is used for file uploads using Web Api.  When a file upload occurs, is it loaded into memory and then streamed to a file?  Or is the content read directly (part by part) from the Request content and subsequently streamed to a file (thereby reducing server memory allocation).  I am trying to determine if a large file will be loaded into memory before being saved to a file using this class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are written to disk during the request. You can see this yourself [here in the source code](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/2abdc3a0a539#src/System.Net.Http.Formatting/MultipartFileStreamProvider.cs) where `FileStream`s are created in a root path and returned from `GetStream` for each distinct part.

Comment: that's not entirely accurate - it will *always* use "Body_" as the name, unless you override the method that gets the file name. That's by design - for security reasons.

Comment: @FilipW Ah, right.. I should probably just remove the sentence altogether from the answer since it's not directly related.